# Getting Segmentation Faults in my ARM program

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I have been writing a program that asks the user to input a number, and then checks if the number is a multiple of two. However, when I try to run the program, it says: Please enter a number? Segmentation fault

Here is the actual code for the program:

```
// Program to test if a number is a multiple of two
.data
question:       .asciz "Please enter a number? "
after_question: .set question_length, after_question - question
userInput:      .space 25
            .space 1, '\n'
notPrime:     .asciz " is not a multiple of two."
prime:       .asciz " is a multiple of two."

.text
.include "io.h"
.global _start
.extern divide, checkRemainder, getn, printn
_start:

mov r0, #1                  /* standard output */
ldr r1, =question           /* r1 - prompt */
mov r2, #question_length
mov r7, #4                  /* write system call*/
svc #0

bl getn
mov r8, r0

bl divide
bl checkRemainder

mov r8, #1
cmp r4, r8
bne notPrimeMessage
beq primeMessage

exit:
    mov r7, #exit
    svc 0

notPrimeMessage:

mov r0, #1                  /* standard output */
  ldr r1, =notPrime         /* r1 ← &question */
  mov r2, #prime - notPrime     /* r2 ← sizeof(question) */

  mov r7, #4                  /* select system call 'write' */
  svc #0                      /* perform the system call */

  ldr r1, =userInput
  mov r0, #1
  mov r2, #25
  svc 0
  b exit

  primeMessage:

  mov r0, #1                    /* standard output */
    ldr r1, =prime          /* r1 ← &greeting */
    mov r2, #prime - notPrime       /* r2 ← sizeof(question) */

    mov r7, #4                  /* select system call 'write' */
    svc #0                      /* perform the system call */

    ldr r1, =userInput
    mov r0, #1
    mov r2, #25
    svc 0
    b exit

.end
```

It appears the issue is somewhere on line 3, of the first program, but I am at a loss for ideas. For those asking, here is the line specifically:

```
question:       .asciz "Please enter a number? "
```

It may have something to do with my external subroutines, but I can't be sure. Just in case, here they are:
divide.s

```
@ divide.s
@ a subroutine that implements integer division and modulus
@ PARAMETERS:
@ R0 - dividend
@ R1 - divisor
@ RETURN VALUES
@ R0 - quotient
@ R1 - modulus (remainder)
@ LIMITATIONS:
@ Only works with positive numbers
@ ERROR CHECKING:
@ If either dividend or divisor is negative, or divisor is zero, returns -1

.global divide

divide:
    push {r6,lr}        // save r6 and return address
    movs r2, r0     // copy dividend to R2
    bmi error       // check dividend < 0
    mov r0, #0      // clear r0 to initialize quotient
    movs r6, r1     // copy divisor to r6
    ble error       // check divisor <= 0
    mov r1, r2      // copy dividend to r1
again:
    subs r1, r1, r6     // subtract divisor
    bmi done        // if negative, stop
    add r0, r0, #1      // count successful subtractions
    b again         // subtract again
error:
    mov r0, #-1     // error code
done:
    add r1, r1, r6      // normalize remainder
return:
    pop {r6, pc}        // retreive r6 and return address
.end
```

checkRemainder.s:

```
@ Check remainder subroutine
@ Subroutine that checks the remainder to see if it is a multiple of another number
@ Parameters:
@ R5 - quotient
@ R7 - constant for comparison
@ R4 - true or false value (0 for false, 1 for true)

.global checkRemainder

checkRemainder:
push {r4, r6, r5, r7, lr}
ldrb r5, [r0]
mov r7, #0
cmp r5, r7
movne r4, #0
moveq r4, #1
pop {r4, r6, r5, r7, pc}
```

getn.s:

```
@ a subroutine to input a decimal number from the keyboard
@ Parameters: none
@ Return values:
@ r0 - binary value
@ r1 - error code: 0 for success, -1 for value error, -2 for invalid character
@ Error handling
@ has a limit of signed values in 32 bits
@ will return -1 if value would exceed these limits
@ returns -2 if there are invalid characters
.include "io.h"
.data
.set buff_size, 12
Buffer:
    .space buff_size
.text
    .globl getn
    .extern read
getn:
    push {r2-r7,r10,lr}
    // save registers,
    mov r0, #STDIN
    ldr r1, =Buffer
    mov r2, #buff_size
    bl read
    cmp r0, #buff_size      // check for excess characters
    bgt ValueError
    add r1, r0, #-1         // adjusted count of characters
convert:
    ldr r2, =Buffer         @ pointer to buffer
    mov r0, #0                  @ clear sum
    mov r4, #0                  @ clear sign flag
    add r5, r2, r1          @ pointer to end of string
    mov r10, #10                // setup multiplier
getChar:
    ldrb r3, [r2]               @ get a character
    cmp r3, #'-'                @ check for minus sign
    bne continue
    mvn r4, r4                  @ toggle sign flag
    add r2, r2, #1          @ increment pointer
    sub r1, r1, #1          @ decrement count of characters
    b getChar
continue:
    cmp r2, r5                  @ check for end of buffer
    bpl ValueError
    subs r3, r3, #0x30  @ convert character to value
    bmi CharacterError  @ error if negative
    cmp r3, #9
    bgt CharacterError  @ error if > 9
    add r0, r0, r3          @ add value to sum
    subs r1, r1, #1         @ decrement count
    beq exit                    @ exit if zero
    mul r0, r10, r0         @ multiply by ten
    add r2, r2, #1
    b getChar                       @ get another character
ValueError:
    mov r1, #-1                 @ error code
    b exit
CharacterError:
    mov r1, #-2
exit:
    movs r4, r4
    bpl done
    mvn r0, r0              @ take two's complement
    add r0, r0, #1
done:
    // restore registers, return
    pop {r2-r7,r10,pc}
.end
```

Comment: Which is line 3?  Line 3 of what?

Comment: Try using a debugger to find the place where the segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: To clear up the confusion, it's line 3 of the first program, here it is:
```
question:       .asciz "Please enter a number? "
```

Comment: The error is definitely not on that line, it's in the code after your program prints that message.

Comment: The `ldrb r5, [r0]` in `CheckRemainder` is extremely suspicious. `r0` isn't listed in the comments and `divide` returns a number not an address in `r0`.

Comment: Try to put `_start:` before `#include "io.h"`... it is not clear what gets initial control.  Also you can put a premature exit.  Did it even ask a question, etc.

Comment: Jester's comment worked to get rid of the error, thank you.